Error in installing fast text-Could not build wheels for fasttext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I was trying to install fast test using
pip install fasttext

But this gives me error like this.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I want to use fasttext_embedding of the fast text

Are you on windows - try pip install fasttext-wheel (https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1343)
